# Can I use Perl CGI::Sessions data in PHP?

Tags: php, perl, cgi, session

I'm using Perl's [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI-Session) with MySQL. No problems there.

I want to incorporate some other languages, most notably PHP, to use the same session cookie.  How would I do that?

Almost the entire site is in Perl, but I want to use free PHP things, like forums and mediawiki, and still use the same session cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried this, but see the [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) function. Some frameworks ([like CakePHP](https://trac.cakephp.org/browser/branches/1.2.x.x/cake/libs/session.php)) use this to store the session in a database. Maybe you could write some code to use the same session as perl, prepending this script to your forum, wiki, etc.

Comment: Mediawiki already has hooks to allow you to determine how the session is read, but I don't know (exactly) how to parse the CGI::Session object into php..

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [PHP::Session](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/PHP-Session-0.27/lib/PHP/Session.pm) module. Check out [Using Perl Code from PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/1712) for other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CGI::Session, you could change the serializer to YAML, and then use PHP to parse YAML.

Alternatively, if you find YAML parsing difficult, you could write your own serializer for CGI::Session, e.g. using JSON, which you can more easily parse. Than you would just use the same session id in PHP as the one you use in Perl.